# Derivative of a composite function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

There are two functions f(x) and g(x):

[f(x) and g(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4nFZ.jpg)

I need to differentiate:

(a) g ∘ f  using the chain rule

(b) h, where h = g ∘ f

I found the partial derivatives of f and g with respect to both variables, but I don’t know how to plug one function into another i.e. how to create g(f(x)).

Any help/hint is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is $h$ different from $g \circ f$?

Comment: I was also wondering that, but that was asked in the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobians are:  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\begin{pmatrix}2x_1& 2x_2\end{pmatrix}$.

Now we should multiply (after plugging $f$ into the Jacobian of $g$), and get:  $\begin{pmatrix}4x_1&4x_2\end{pmatrix}$

As a check, note that $g\circ f(x)=2x_1^2+2x_2^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but I know that rule. I don’t know how to apply it. I thought that I should take partial derivatives of both functions and then create the Jacobian matrix or gradient and then plug f(x) in g′ i.e. in the gradient somehow like in the formula.

Comment: Right.  I hadn't looked at the link yet.  Let's try it.   I will edit.

Comment: ∂f/ ∂x1=(1, 1)
∂f/ ∂x2=(1, -1)
The Jacobian matrix is: Jf(x1, x2) = (1, 1, 1,-1) 
Sorry, but I don’t know how to create the matrix here in the comments, so I’ve written the answers this way.
∂g/∂x1=2x1
∂g/∂x2=2x2
The gradient is: ∇(x1, x2) = (2x1, 2x2) 
Of course the gradient should be written as a vector.
Now I don’t know how to plug f(x) in g′

Comment: Oh, sorry! I hadn’t seen your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry,  I think I erred.  You _do_ need to plug $f$ into the Jacobian of $g$.